# Turn off Glassfish Log Rotation

Tags: rotation, glassfish-3

I know that it is possible to configure log rotation options based on file size. I could not find and option to turn off the rotation rules completely at Glassfish 3.1?

Is it possible to disable log rotation at Glassfish 3.1?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off log rotation by setting the `File Rotation Limit` (server-config -> Logger Settings) to **0 bytes** in the glassfish admin gui or via asadmin command:

```
asadmin set-log-attributes --target server
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationLimitInBytes=0
```

Answer (score 0):

When I try to set a 0 bytes limit in the admin GUI (GF 4.1), I get this error:

```
Invalid logging attribute name or value com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationLimitInBytes=0.
```

This seems to be consistent with [this](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-6668) thread, which also suggests to modify the value directly in `logging.properties` instead. Doing that worked for me and disabled log rotation.