# Automatic log file rotation in GlassFish

Tags: rotation, glassfish, logfile

I tried a crazy thing about setting attributes to session for a client request.

```
for(int i=0; i<i+1; i++) {
    session.setAttribute("dumpData" + i , new Object().toString());
    System.out.println("$$$$$$$$---  Count = " + i);
}
```

I just want to know how much the session can take. But while looking into log file for the count of attributes, I found a strange thing `log file rotation...`, this was also in the log file content. First I searched in the entire project for any file(s) which is logging `log file rotation...`, but there were no files. So I was wondering whether the `GlassFish` is automatically rotating the log files. If yes can any body explain or show any useful links with explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Glassfish is automatically rotating the log files.

From [Oracle GlassFish Server Administration Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gklmn.html)

> Oracle GlassFish Server by default rotates log files when they reach 2
>   MB in size. However, you can change the default rotation settings. For
>   example, you can change the file size at which the server rotates the
>   log file or you can configure a server to rotate log files based on a
>   time interval. In addition to changing when rotation occurs, you can
>   also:
>
> - Specify the maximum number of rotated files that can accumulate.
>
> By default, Oracle GlassFish Server does not limit the number of
>   rotated log files that are retained. However, you can set a limit.
>   After the number of log files reaches this limit, subsequent file
>   rotations delete the oldest rotated log file.
>
> - Rotate the log file manually.
>
> A manual rotation forces the immediate rotation of the target log
>   file.

Have a look at `/GLASSFISH_FOLDER/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/logging.properties`. It should be easy to understand. For detailed explanations have a look at the Glassfish Server Administration Guide.

**See also:**

- [Turn off Glassfish Log Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152905/turn-off-glassfish-log-rotation)